# Layout using divs

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

I have done some research on layouts and apparently using HTML `tables` to layout your page is BAD. So the alternative is to make use of div's.

I have the following layout designed and want to know how I would implement this with the use of div's. Specifically, how I would get the 3 panels at the top to be aligned vertically with a panel at the bottom that stretched the length of all three panels.

Would I be able to do this purely with CSS and HTML?

Here is the design:
[image]

Comment: Yes - check this out - http://www.layzilla.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<table>` element has no semantical significance when used for layouts. It should be used for data grids only.

That said, CSS has a good alternative:

```
display: table;
```

and

```
display: table-cell;
```

See this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/c6p7gd3y/1/).

Your layout consists of two separate "tables". There is also `table-row` to create columns with the same width over multiple rows. It doesn't have alternatives to colspan, thead and other table specific elements, but it should do the job for a simple layout.

Comment: This is really an interesting way of doing it, but what if I need to have each table cell with a different width?

Comment: I edited the fiddle to make it look more like your example, with different widths (I used the child pseudo selector for that but it can be class names as well)

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for... I did some reading up and I really like this method of doing it. It maintains the idea of using a table without the fallback of the table! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's perfectly possible in pure CSS and HTML.

Consider this code:

```css
.small-box {
          width: 200px;
          height: 200px;
          float: left;
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
        
        .large-box {
          width: 606px;
          height: 200px;
          clear: both;
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
```

```html
<div class="small-box">some content</div>
       <div class="small-box">Some other content</div>
       <div class="small-box">Another content</div>
       <div class="large-box">Large box content</div>
```

The most important thing here is the use of `float` and `clear` attributes. You can make divs stick together in a single line with `float` attribute and if you want something beneath them use `clear` to 'push' the next element below. One thing though, to use `float`, the element has to have `width` attribute defined.

Comment: You say the element has to have the width property defined, is it fine if I define it using a % e.g. 50%? If so then this is perfect! I never knew about `clear` before

Comment: Thanks for the help. It does exactly what I want It to do, I just prefer jazZRo's method of doing it! thanks!